# Simple java HttpClient program not working

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have HttpClient 4.1. Please have a look at following program:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class SysCommands {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
            System.out.println("Initial part");
            HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
            HttpResponse resp = c.execute(method);
            System.out.println("Method executed");
            String s = "";
            resp.getHeaders(s);
            System.out.println("headers are "+s);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException`. What could be wrong?

Comment: Where exactly does it throw that exception? Your code works for me. Also, how is the Runtime/Process code relevat to your question, if it isn't please remove.

Comment: try e.printStackTrace() instead of System.out.println(e) to get the full stack trace. Also, your reps.getHeaders(s) returns an array, s is not changed.

Comment: right after execute. and it's for google.com only. I tried www.affinity.com, it worked. How come !!

Comment: Unrelated to that, I highly recommend something like `String string = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());` instead of rolling your own BufferedReader/InputStreamReader/loop thing.

Comment: I did, but same happening. Doing that on google.com gives me error. Does google somehow avoids such  calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that google redirects you to your "local" google site. I live in the Netherlands, and when I get www.google.com, it responds with a HTTP 302 redirect to www.google.nl.

I'm not sure how the default http client is configured, but it is possible that it does not follow redirects by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using HttpURLConnection instead of HttpClient?

Comment: I just tried some different site, it worked. However google.com didn't. I don't know about HttpURLConnection. In most of the examples HttpClient is being used so I tried that. I will check it out. Thanks